# The definition of a function series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

I have the function series $f_n(x)$ defined as: 
$$ f_n(x) = \frac{xe^{-nx}}{\ln(n)} $$

where $ x\in \mathbb{R}~~ \& ~~ \forall n \geq 2 $.

The question askes for two things:

$1.$ to specify the domain where the series $ \sum_{n \geq 2} f_n(x)$ is defined (domain of definition).

$2.$ to study if the function is continues over the interval $]0, \infty[$.

I already solved the second question with no problem, but I don't know how to solve the first one! I would appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: @guy3141 Why ? we usually use the Weierstrass to evaluate if an infinite series of functions converges uniformly and absolutely.  I don't understand how could this help me to find the domain needed above in the first question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$, then you always have $f_n(x)=0$, and therefore the sequence converges.

If $x>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-nx}=0$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}}{\log n}=0$ too.

Finally, if $x<0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{\log n}=\infty$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}}{\log n}=-\infty$; in particular, your sequence diverges.

Comment: so the domain where the series converges is $[0, \infty)$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.